# Relationship with doctoral advisor?

Tags: phd, advisor, physics

My question is that do most people keep in touch with their doctoral advisors after they graduate? Do doctoral advisors forget their PhD students after the students get their degree?

I am mainly asking about math/physics if that makes a difference.

Comment: Do you mean professionally(which I think you do)? Also, if you can then please specify that what do you mean by 'forget' - are you asking that they abandon collaborating or stop discussing with them, i.e. treat them like ex-colleagues?

Comment: For almost everyone it is worth spending a bit of effort to keep the lines of communication open so that you aren't forgotten. An annual update on your career would be welcomed by many. A periodic visit in person, just to chat, is worth doing if it can be managed. You are their academic heir. Most people value that relationship.

Comment: Is this about students staying in academia, or about students leaving academia?

Answer (score 5):

I very much doubt any of them "forget" in the sense of "Who are you, and how did you get this number?"

The relationship one has with their former advisor will depend on both the advisor, the graduate, and their relationship - and it will evolve over time. Some are happy to go their separate ways, some continue to be long time collaborators or friends, and the amount of political capital they will spend on their former graduates varies wildly.

Some advisors (wisely IMO) step back a little bit to make sure that their former PhD students develop an independent research agenda and voice, and clearly have a separate career from their advisor.

But it all depends. Personally? I keep in touch with my advisor, see him at conferences (back before COVID-19), and when the opportunity is right, we collaborate, but we don't actively seek out those opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your current relationship and on who you & your advisor are as a person in general.

If your current relationship runs smoothly and your research interests continue to coincide you may continue to publish joint papers. I have seen that happening long after a former PhD student graduates - even after they get faculty positions.

However I have also seen former advisors turning competitive and trying to exclude former lab members from the continuation of a project. I would guess in that case one would not want to try to continue to have any kind of friendly relationship with the advisor...